# How to use a sentinel to trigger end of vector?

Tags: c++, vector

I'm new to programming (in general) and C++ (in particular).  I'm learning vectors and am trying to write a simple program that:

1. allows the user to enter a vector of students' test scores
2. when the user types the sentinel (-1 in this case), the vector terminates
3. outputs a tally of the student's grades

Here's my code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

const int SENTINEL = -1;

vector<int> studentGrades = { 0 };
int myInput;

int main()
{
    do
    {
        cout << "Please enter a student's grade: ";
        cin >> myInput;

        if (myInput < 1000)
        {
            studentGrades[myInput]++;
        }

        studentGrades.push_back(myInput);

    } while (myInput != SENTINEL);


    cout << "\n";

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        cout << i << " grade(s) of " << studentGrades[i] << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Two questions:

1) Can anyone provide guidance on why this code is only allowing me to enter one student's grade?

2) Is the for loop that compute the "tally" correct?

Thanks in advance for taking a look,
Ryan

*** REVISED CODE ***

@ JCx - this is the revised code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

const int SENTINEL = -1;

vector<int> studentGrades = { 0 };
int myInput;

int main()
{
    do
    {
        cout << "Please enter a student's grade (or -1 to QUIT): ";
        cin >> myInput;

        if (myInput < 1000)
        {
            studentGrades.at(myInput)++;
        }

        studentGrades.push_back(myInput);

    } while (myInput != SENTINEL);


    cout << "\n";

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        cout << i << " grade(s) of " << studentGrades.at(myInput) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

and, I'm seeing this error:

Unhandled exception at 0x7707C42D

Microsoft C++ exception: std::out_of_range at memory location 0x0035F890

Comment: Your `if` statement does not make sense, with the way your vector has been declared.  To use the sentinel, you should `break` after the `cin` if `myInput == SENTINEL`.

Comment: Should I completely delete that if statement?

Comment: Yes, and replace it with what I suggested above.

Answer (score 0):

There's more than one problem.  The attempt to access studentGrades[-1] when the users enters your sentinel value, and the fact that the default vector only contains an entry for 0 and the use of push_back.

Let's just walk through some of the problems:

- User runs program. User enters 100.  studentGrades[100] is out of range.  Undefined behaviour occurs as the vector only has one element.
- User runs program, enters -1 studentGrades[-1] is out of range.
- User runs program, enters 0.  studentGrades[0] is in range, incremented to 1.  studentGrades.push_back(1) adds an element to the vector studentGrades[1] is now also equal to 1.

As a great starting point, if you swap your subscript vector references for the vector **at** method as I've shown below you will get out-of-range errors which will help (a lot). The code below still needs work but at least you'll have run-time errors instead of odd behaviour.

```
int main()
{
    do
    {
        cout << "Please enter a student's grade: ";
        cin >> myInput;

        if (myInput < 1000)
        {
            studentGrades.at(myInput)++;
        }

        studentGrades.push_back(myInput);

    } while (myInput != SENTINEL);


    cout << "\n";

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        cout << i << " grade(s) of " << studentGrades.at(myInput) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I think if I was implementing this I'd be using std::map instead of a vector.  It would let you have a studentGrade[1000] without having to allocate memory for studentGrade[0] to [999] first.

However as you are learning about std::vector check out vector::resize to set the vector big enough for the required elements, std::vector::size to find out whether you need to increase the size.  You could then ditch the push_back.

**References**

vector::at http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/at/

vector::size http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/size/

Comment: that definitely helps a lot.  Thank you.  The run time error that I'm seeing is "error C3867:'std::vector<int,std::allocator<_Ty>>::at': function call missing argument list; use '&std::vector<int,std::allocator<_Ty>>::at' to create a pointer to member"..... I've never seen anything like this before.  Do you know what it means?

Comment: That's odd. Pop the code you have up?  The error I'd expect you to get is: libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::out_of_range: vector

Comment: I just posted it in the REVISED section above.

Comment: Right - that's your out of range error. You are referencing outside the vectors size.  See my answer I updated about 15 mins ago.  You need a bigger vector, or to use map, or to resize it appropriately.